# Is there a DB that will allow the same field name with different cases?

Tags: database-design, schema

Is there a DB that will allow a user to create a table with two fields, one calls `MYFIELD`, the other called `myfield`?

Comment: Yes. In SQL Server it depends on the collation of the database whether object names are case sensitive or not.

Comment: I think the larger question is "Why would you do that?" You will quickly have confusion about which field means what and how you're managing your data.  Maybe if you provide some context, we can offer you a better solution?

Comment: Is there a brand of bleach that doesn't have all these silly poison warnings all over the label?

Comment: Yes. Every ANSI compatible DBMS, because `"FOO"`, `"Foo"` and `"foo"` are different names (because they are quoted identifiers)

Comment: In short: You *can* do it almost everywhere, you *shouldn't* do it anywhere.

Comment: Is this the kind of criteria you're going to use to choose your database platform? This is like choosing a house based on the color of the nearest fire hydrant and whether it matches the tie you're wearing today.

Comment: Add my voice to the "no" crowd. Case-sensitivity causes far more confusion and annoyance and grief and anger that any advantages it provides. Actually, thinking about it, what advantages does it provide?

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker: it make painkillers' vendors richer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. You have to change the database collation from CI (case insensitive) to CS (case sensitive).
You can do that by using T-SQL, such as:

```
ALTER DATABASE TEST
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Or in SQL Server Management Studio:

1. Right-click the database in Object Explorer
2. Select Properties
3. Select the Options tab
4. Change a new collation in the drop-down menu
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, object names default to UPPERCASE. But object names can be overridden to be exact case.

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE 
(
  MYFIELD VARCHAR2(20) 
, "myfield" VARCHAR2(20) 
);
table MYTABLE created.
```

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, DB2 also allows it:

```
$ db2

db2 => CREATE TABLE "do not do this"("Horrible_Idea" INTEGER, HORRIBLE_IDEA INTEGER)
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 3):

Any ISO compliant SQL, such as PostgreSQL, when using quoted identifiers.  With your example it would look like

```
CREATE TABLE strange (
    "myfield" text,
    "MYFIELD" text,
    "MyField" text
);
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), too.

Comment: A short code example would be nice. Maybe even a reference to the manual? [Hint.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)